# No me aparece la carpeta .bashrc

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows, macos, wsl

No me aparece esa carpeta y no puedo configurar mi terminal a mi gusto y agregarle alias a los comandos que con mas frecuencia uso.

¿Cómo creo yo ese archivo? ¿hay alguna estructura en particular?, uso WSL.

Comment: Cada usuario de tu sistema tiene su propia `.bashrc` en su home directory. Para modificar tu .bashrc utilizando el editor vim o nano solo tienes que ejecutar `vim ~/.bashrc` y ahí la modificas. Aclarar que `~` te sitúa en el home directory de tu usuario. Importante que sepas que si ejecutas un `ls -l ~` para ver el contenido de tu home directory no verás el archivo . bashrc ya que este esta oculto (.). Para listar archivos y directorios ocultos ejecuta `ls -la`.

Comment: Para tener alias de forma permanente colo le hago, puesto que los introduzco en .bashrc y actualizo la terminal y no me los reconoce. Lei que es recomn¿endable crealos en otro lado, concretamente en .bash_aliases, pero igual, los pongo ahi y no pasa nada.

Comment: Para añadir un alias tienes que editar la `.bashrc` y añadir el alias que quieres crear en una nueva línea con la siguiente sintaxis : `alias [nombreAlias]=[comando]`. (Obviamente sin los []). Después de eso tienes que "recargar" de nuevo tu .bashrc  para que se apliquen los cambios. Para eso ejecuta un `source ~/.bashrc` o bien `. ~/.bashrc`.

Comment: Ten en cuenta la terminal que estás ejecutando por ejemplo en Mac viene por defecto el "zsh" y este lee la configuración desde `.zshrc`

Comment: Si te refieres al archivo .bashrc, puedes ver el contenido por defecto de Ubuntu. Es de código abierto ;) https://gist.github.com/marioBonales/1637696